# AppleScript Photos folder reference doesn't work inside subroutine - why?

Tags: applescript

I'm a beginner with AppleScript. What I'm looking to do here is tell Apple's Photos app to create a new folder inside an existing folder. Ultimately I'm looking to recursively clone a folder structure, so I need to be able to pass the parent folder to a subroutine and have the subroutine create the folder.

I can create the subfolder within the parent folder if I do it all in the same context, but if I do the exact same thing inside a subroutine, passing in a reference to the parent folder, it fails with this error:

```
error "Can’t make folder id \"1632F3F7-D00F-42DB-B9B3-F781D5DDAFD8/L0/020\" of application \"Photos\" into the expected type." number -1700 from folder id "1632F3F7-D00F-42DB-B9B3-F781D5DDAFD8/L0/020"
```

I figure this has something to do with the fact that `theParentFolder` is passed to the subroutine by reference rather than by value, but I'm tried a few unsuccessful attempts to work around this and failed.

```
on createFolderInSubRoutine(parentFolder)
    if not (folder named "bar" exists) then make new folder named "bar" at parentFolder -- fails
end createFolderInSubRoutine

tell application "Photos"
    set theParentFolder to folder "My Parent Folder"
    if not (folder named "foo" exists) then make new folder named "foo" at theParentFolder -- works
    my createFolderInSubRoutine(theParentFolder)
    return
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution:

```
on createFolderInSubRoutine(parentFolder)
    tell parentFolder
        if not (folder named "bar" exists) then make new folder named "bar" at parentFolder
    end tell
end createFolderInSubRoutine

tell application "Photos"
    set theParentFolder to folder "My Parent Folder"
    my createFolderInSubRoutine(theParentFolder)
    return
end tell
```

I don't fully understand *why* this works, but I'm happy to move on knowing that it *does* work.